# Solving an integral with multiple limits

Tags: real-analysis

I need help with the following integral, since I have absolutely no idea how to tackle this:

$\displaystyle {\iint_{ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 \leq N; x - \theta y > 0; 1 < \left| \frac{x-\theta' y}{x-\theta y} \right| \leq \epsilon_0^2 } dxdy} 
= \frac{N \cdot\log(\epsilon_0)}{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}$,

where

- $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$
- $b^2 > 4ac$
- $\theta = \frac{-b + \sqrt{D}}{2a} $
- $\theta' = \frac{-b - \sqrt{D}}{2a}$
- $D=b^2-4ac$
- $\epsilon_0 > 1$ const.
- $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ is a quadratic form

Does anyone has a magical idea how to solve this integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the change of variables
$$\begin{cases}u=x-\theta y, \\
v=x-\theta' y
\end{cases}$$
integral can be rewritten as
$$\iint\limits_{G}{|J|\,du\,dv}$$
where 
$G=\left\lbrace {(u,\,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2\vert\;\;\; auv\leqslant{N},\ 0 < {u}<\left\vert {v} \right\vert \leqslant \varepsilon_{0}^{2}}{u} \right\rbrace$ and Jacobian $J=\det\dfrac{\partial(x,\,y)}{\partial(u,\,v)}= \det\pmatrix{1 & -\theta \\ 1 & -\theta'}^{-1}=\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{D}}.$

Comment: Isn't $J = \left( \det\pmatrix{1 & -\theta \\ 1 & -\theta'} \right)^{-1} =  \frac{a}{\sqrt{D}}$. If yes, then for $v > 0$ I get the desired result.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks, i edited answer.